# How do I make Intellij not lose highlighting when the window scrolls?

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

When I hold shift and hit end of line, or scroll down the page in IntelliJ the highlighting resets to start at the place where the caret has moved to. Does anyone know how to stop this from happening?

Another thing I have noticed that happens actually and seems like this is related is that if the text is off the editor and I hit end, it doesn't move the caret to the end of the line, but shifts the editor to the next "page" and realigns the caret at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Did you install any plug-ins? Does it happen on a clean installation?

Comment: The only plugin I have is the scala plugin, and I believe it has happened since I cleanly installed it.

Comment: Try to disable the plug-in until it's fixed and make sure to report at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/SCL . Also try IDEA 12 EAP with the new Scala plug-in and see if it works there.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the issue has happened since I installed intellij, before the scala plugin was added. Also, everyone else on my team of 15 people has the scala plugin and they don't have the issue, I can't really work without that plugin unfortunately.Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Does it happen on other machines with the same IDEA version?

Comment: My bad, turns out I had another plugin installed IdeaVim which caused the issue, it was horrible so I had disabled it a long time ago, and completely forgot about it. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered out what the issue was thanks to CrazyCoder, I went through the plugins and determined that I had the IdeaVim plugin installed, but not active so I didn't realize it was doing anything. I have uninstalled it and the issue has gone away.

Answer (score 2):

It's a known bug [VIM-279](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-279) of IdeaVim.